# Cakephp 3 _matching, how format results data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-3.x

My query looks like:

```
$test = $this->Producers->find()
    ->hydrate(true)
    ->select(['Producers.id','Producers.name', 'Products.id', 'Products.name']);

    $test->matching(
            'Products.Categories', function ($q) {
                return $q->where(['Categories.id' => 22]);
    } );
```

This query use inner join and returned data naturally looks like

```
|Producers_id|Producers_name|Products_id|Products_name|
-------------------------------------------------------
|1           |Canon         |1          |EOS 1000D    |
-------------------------------------------------------
|1           |Canon         |2          |EOS 300D     |
-------------------------------------------------------
|1           |Canon         |3          |EOS 50D      |
-------------------------------------------------------
|3           |Nikon         |6          |D600         |
-------------------------------------------------------
|3           |Nikon         |7          |D100         |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

In view, after foreach iteration i have producer and product for each row:

```
=============================
Producer: Canon
-----------------------------
EOS 1000D
=============================
Producer: Canon
-----------------------------
EOS 300D
=============================
Producer: Canon
-----------------------------
EOS 50D
=============================
```

But i expect formated data like:

```
=============================
Producer: Canon
-----------------------------
EOS 1000D
-----------------------------
EOS 300D
-----------------------------
EOS 50D
=============================
Producer: Nikon
-----------------------------
D600
-----------------------------
D100
=============================
```

What is the best data formatting practice? In view, or model/controller? Maybe use mapReduce()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice or not, using `Cake\Collection\Collection`, you can group the results:

```
$collection = new Collection($test);
$byProducer = $collection->groupBy('Producers_name')->toArray();
```

This would result in:

```
[Canon] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Producers_id] => 1
                [Producers_name] => Canon
                [Products_id] => 1
                [Products_name] => EOS 1000D
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Producers_id] => 1
                [Producers_name] => Canon
                [Products_id] => 2
                [Products_name] => EOS 300D
            ) ...
    )

[Nikon] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Producers_id] => 3
                [Producers_name] => Nikon
                [Products_id] => 6
                [Products_name] => D600
            ) ...
    )
```

Comment: `$test` [**already is a collection**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects) (kind of). Also you'll have to group by `name`, with the query shown by the OP, there will be no `Producers_name` in the resulting entites.

Comment: code-kobolt:
works great, thank You!

ndm You have right, only need to:

    `$byProducer = $test->groupBy('Producers_name')->toArray();`

without "`use Cake\Collection\Collection;`" and `$collection = new Collection($test);`